# Is there any way to edit partial design using Scriban?

Tags: sxa, scriban

Is it possible to style the `partial design` using the **scriban** template. For example, I just made the new header partial design for my new site, and I am now clueless on how to style it. I have been styling my other components using Scriban, beacuse I find it really easy to use (for me at least).
What is your preffered way of designing/styling the **header** **partial** **design** in **SXA Sitecore**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partial design works just the same as the other items/pages when it comes to adding components and styling those. You can open the partial design in the Experience Editor and add all the components you want - including the variants (where you can use Scriban) and styles if needed.

You will notice that a partial design has a layout definition, so you can also edit the layout just as you are used to with other items.

More information in the official docs: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/102/sitecore-experience-accelerator/create-and-change-a-partial-design.html

Comment: So I can just add the new for example Link List with the Scriban template variant on the header partial design, and it would look like the way I designed it, with CSS and everything?

Comment: Yes, your partial design can use the variants (with Scriban) for any component.

Comment: Thank you for explaining to me properly!